# Can replaceState() in JavaScript be used to change document title and contents?

Tags: jquery

How can I add a tag `<title>Update</title>` and `<div id="content">Update</div>`?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $( "a" ).click(function() {
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        if(url != window.location){
            history.replaceState(null, null, url);
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

I need to update eg `<title>Home</title>` to `<title>About</title>` and `<div id = "content">Home content</ div>` to `<div id="content">About content</div>` at the transition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really unclear what you want to acheive, but if your goal is to set the displayed title of the page, set `document.title`:

```
document.title = "Update";
```

And if you want to add a `div`:

```
$('<div id="content">Update</div>').appendTo(document.body);
```

That appends to the body of the page (at the bottom). If you want the `div` to be somewhere else, you'll want to append it to some other element in the DOM. You can use CSS selectors (plus some additional things) to choose which element to add to.

If you do that twice, the resulting DOM document will be invalid, as you cannot have two elements with the same `id`. If you want to update the existing one if it's there:

```
var $div = $("#content");
if (!$div[0]) {
    $div = $('<div id="content"></div>');
    $div.appendTo(document.body);
}
$div.text("Update"): // Or $div.html("HTML markup here")
```

Comment: You do not understand I need to update title eg `<title>Home</title>` to `<title>About</title>` in the transition! Help me please!

Comment: For example a http://takazudo.github.io/jQuery.LazyJaxDavis/doc/

Comment: @KYRAN: I understand. The above **does** update the title, and the div.